# Raspberry Pi 4B - how to associate an application to a display

Tags: raspberry-pi, startup, display, raspberry-pi4

Assume two applications running on a RPi 4B, each one using a screen (connected to the HDMI ports).

Requirements:

1. Both applications are started at boot time.
2. Each application must use a specific screen (something like a screen for engine information and the other for GPS mapping).
3. The RPi is dedicated to running these applications.

How does one go about this? I found information on how to start an application during boot, but nothing about associating application X to display Y...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for [raspberrypi.se], as it is not a programming question.

Comment: @Ken - I am not entirely familiar with the stackoverflow structure... Is there anywhere more appropriate?

Comment: :-) I gave you a link to the more appropriate site in my first comment. It's [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: So you did - thanks !